# Pages correctly shows my iCloud documents on iPhone, but not on iPad

Tags: ios, icloud, pages

Pages correctly shows my iCloud documents on iPhone, but not on iPad.

The main page is enpty and I can only create new documents.

I've tried to reinstall the app, deactivate the iCloud Pages settings in the preferences, both in the iCloud menu, and specific Pages app (Use iCloud)

[image]
[image]

Also, if ai create a new document, it is not synch to iCloud, it is stuck as if there was no internet connection.
[image]